# Можете подсказать альтернативу sqlsrv

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, yii

ранее делал запрос со встроенной процедурой get_prod и входным параметром prod

```
$db = new yii\db\Connection([
    'driverName' => 'sqlsrv',
    'dsn' => 'sqlsrv:Server=111.111.11.111;Database=MAIN',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
]);

$SN = 123321123;

$result = $db->createCommand("EXECUTE get_prod :prod")
    ->bindValue(':prod',$SN)
    ->queryAll();
```

но сложилось так, что sqlsrv я не могу использовать больше на сервере
пожалуйста, можете подсказать как это подключение будет выглядеть через
PDO::__construct()
или
odbc_connect() или может ещё есть какие -то варианты

Огромное вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Как-бы Yii2 из коробки использует PDO, а от туда прям кландайк на разные базы данных.

Выбираешь БД в замен SQLSERVER, и выбираешь из списка себе PDO DSN.
Открываем сайт: https://electrictoolbox.com/php-pdo-dsn-connection-string/

Чем SQLSERVER не угодил? Ближайшие замены ему Postgres и MySQL.

Comment: Выкинь к чёрту ODBC! wiki: `ODBC — это программный интерфейс доступа к базам данных, разработанный компанией Microsoft`  он нужен только для соединение через Windows ODBC драйверы. Используй чистые PDO драйверы. `но на сервер нет возможности драйвер поставить` Чё серьёзно что-ли?  С каких это пор драйвер `php-pdo-mssql` совместно с PHP из репы не идёт? Ещё раз говорю выкинь ODBC к чёрту, это лажа полная.... Её используют 1 раз в 1000 лет и то к супер извращённым микрософтовским соединениям по типу Access, Excel и прочим извращениям опалённого мозга.

Comment: offtop: Я как очень старый пенсионер, когда-то писал софт на Delphi 5-7, вот тогда мы со скрипом слезами и соплями использовали ODBC, для создания первых банковских приложений. Уже тогда нам ODBC приносил только боль и слёзы. И только после появления ZeosDBO все вдруг вздохнули спокойно. Прошло уже лет 25, а мелкийсофт в этом плане нечего не поменял.

Comment: @EugeneX видимо с давних не идет. под винду всегда приходилось расширения pdo для sqlsrv ставить руками.

Comment: @teran слава богу я поздно начал изучать PHP, очень долго и жестко на perl сидел.